# printing graphics images

Tags: graphics, printing

I almost always have the problem of files with graphic images (jpg, png, pdf) printing only one-fourth or less of the size of the full 8.5 x 11 page even though the page setup is correct and the print preview shows a full page output. How can I always get the full page when I want it?

Comment: What printer / printer driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Ubuntu problem. Check your printer's settings. Most probable it is set to print multiple pictures on the same sheet. Look for N-page Up setting or similar.